# Export to Excel in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i am tried to export data to excel sheet.

i tried the following code:

```
var grid = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView();
var dbcontext = new HotelDbContext();
grid.DataSource = dbcontext.Database.SqlQuery<ReportsDTO>("Usp_GetDaysBillReport").ToList();
grid.DataBind();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Marklist.xls");
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
Response.Charset = "";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
grid.RenderControl(htw);
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

i did not get any error and also file not downloaded.

Comment: Where do you have this code (Controller, View, etc)?

Comment: i am having these codes in controller.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following in your controller:

```
    public FileContentResult DownloadExcel()
    {
        var grid = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView();
        var dbcontext = new HotelDbContext();
        grid.DataSource = dbcontext.Database.SqlQuery<ReportsDTO>("Usp_GetDaysBillReport").ToList();
        grid.DataBind();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        grid.RenderControl(htw);

        return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sw.ToString()), 
                    "application/ms-excel", 
                    "Marklist.xls");
    }
```